# How do I use matplotlib correctly to get two graphs in same picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

My codes are shown below

As you can see I am creating a histogram and a vertical line to show a certain threshold. However, I am getting the vertical line and the histogram on two separate graphs. how do I get them to show on the same graph.

be30dayChg is time series and I am creating histogram out of it(just an fyi if anyone interested)

```
be30dayChg = sec[['20yBE']].diff(30)
beVaR99Hist = be30dayChg.quantile(.01)   
plt.axvline(x=np.asscalar(beVaR99Hist), color='r', linestyle='-')
be30dayChg.hist()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
plt.axvline("line params")

plt.bar("Data", hist)
```